# BIND session key

Tags: permissions, bind, session, dns-server, keys

When I restart or start my BIND DNS server, I'm getting the following in the /var/log/messages log file.

```
Jan 26 07:50:30 dev named[306]: could not create /jail/bind-9.9.4-P2/var/run/named/session.key
Jan 26 07:50:30 dev named[306]: failed to generate session key for dynamic DNS: permission denied
```

Any idea why this is the case?  I searched around and it appears to be related to the "key-directory" setting in the named.conf file.  However even if I set this to a writeable directory I'm still seeing this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS/Distro/version?

Comment: @Iain CentOS release 6.5 (Final) with 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.  I downloaded the source for BIND and run ./configure and ./make on my own.  Not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea, `session.key` might not be writeable or the path might not exist.

The BIND option `key-directory` you mention specifies the directory where the public and private DNSSEC key files should be found when performing dynamic update of secure zones.

Try to set the BIND option `session-keyfile` to the pathname of the file into which to write a TSIG session key.
If not specified, the default is `/var/run/named/session.key` (and relative to your chroot jail).

E.g. in `named.conf`'s `options`-section

```
session-keyfile "/var/bind/session.key";
```